# How to train deep and wide model by FTRL optimizer?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I have wide model, and want to incorporate deep model according to [Deep and Wide Model](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.07792.pdf). Should I apply the FTRL operator to every node in the deep part. And how can I quickly modify the existing wide model to integrate the deep part.